# !LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: bibtex, errors, ieeetran

I am creating a lab report and am trying to add a bibliography at the end.  I am fairly new to LaTeX and am not sure what is the case when I receive the missing `\item` message.  My main `.tex` code is:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[margin=0.4in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \title{Lab 12N Report \LaTeX}
    \author{Jeremy Wolfe}
    \maketitle

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{LabReportBib}
\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file, named LabReportBib is:

```
@misc{libretexts_2018, title={Constant Pressure Calorimetry}, url={https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/Calorimetry/Constant_Pressure_Calorimetry}, journal={Chemistry LibreTexts}, publisher={National Science Foundation}, author={Libretexts}, year={2018}, month={Nov}}

@misc{writing advice, title={Writing Advice Home}, 
url={http://advice.writing.utoronto.ca/types-of-writing/lab-report/}, 
journal={Writing Advice}}
```

Any help on making this work would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE:

My used packages are:

```
*File List*
filecontents.sty 2018/05/30 v1.4 Create an external file from within a LaTeX
document
IEEEtran.cls 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
graphicx.sty 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
keyval.sty 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
url.sty 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
amsmath.sty 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
amstext.sty 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
amsbsy.sty 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
amsopn.sty 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
lettrine.sty 2018-08-28 v2.21 (Daniel Flipo)
minifp.sty 2013/12/30 v0.96. Macros for real number operations and a stack
-based programing language.
lettrine.cfg
subcaption.sty 2018/05/01 v1.1-162 Sub-captions (AR)
caption.sty 2018/10/06 v3.3-154 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty 2018/09/12 v1.8c caption3 kernel (AR)
gensymb.sty 2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
geometry.sty 2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
ifpdf.sty 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
ifvtex.sty 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
ifxetex.sty 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
grfext.sty 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
ltxcmds.sty 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty 2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
LRtest.bbl
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I cannot reproduce the error you report with the code you provided. Plus, you have there some bib entries, but make no citations in your MWE. In order for us to understand what's going on, some code that allows us to actually see the error would greatly smooth things.

Comment: I tried adding the citation: \cite{libretexts_2018}  but I get the same message.  I did remove most of my actual code from this post because I believe it was irrelevant to error I am getting.

Answer (score 3):

From the given `bib` file I can see that you have an blank in the key name (`writing advice`) of an entry, which is not allowed. Change it to

```
@misc{writing_advice, 
  title={Writing Advice Home}, 
  url={http://advice.writing.utoronto.ca/types-of-writing/lab-report/}, 
  journal={Writing Advice},
}
```

You did not cite any entry in your code so I added `\nocite{*}` to the following code:

```
\listfiles % <======= to get used packages and version number list
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{libretexts_2018, 
  title={Constant Pressure Calorimetry}, 
  url={https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/Calorimetry/Constant_Pressure_Calorimetry}, 
  journal={Chemistry LibreTexts}, 
  publisher={National Science Foundation}, 
  author={Libretexts}, 
  year={2018}, 
  month={Nov},
}

@misc{writing_advice, 
  title={Writing Advice Home}, 
  url={http://advice.writing.utoronto.ca/types-of-writing/lab-report/}, 
  journal={Writing Advice},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[margin=0.4in]{geometry}


\begin{document}
    \title{Lab 12N Report \LaTeX}
    \author{Jeremy Wolfe}
    \maketitle

\nocite{*} % <==========================================================
\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Please check your log file there are some warning resulting you should have a look at ... Check the log file `*.blg` that there are no warnings and errors inside. Correct all of them step by step ...

The resulting pdf file is:

[image]

## UPDATE:

My used system is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6880 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.12.1)  5 DEC 2018 22:23
```

and the used packages are:

```
 *File List*
filecontents.sty    2018/05/30 v1.4 Create an external file from within a LaTeX document
ieeetran.cls    2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 amsmath.sty    2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
lettrine.sty    2018-08-28 v2.21 (Daniel Flipo)
  minifp.sty    2013/12/30 v0.96. Macros for real number operations and a stack-based programing language.
lettrine.cfg
subcaption.sty    2018/05/01 v1.1-162 Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2018/10/06 v3.3-154 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2018/09/12 v1.8c caption3 kernel (AR)
 gensymb.sty    2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
geometry.sty    2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
```

Comment: Should the part starting at "\RequirePackage... to ...\end{filecontents*} go above the .tex file or stay in the .bib file?

Comment: I've tried running that exact code in TexMaker and I get the same message.  Could it be that I am running an old version of the program?  I've tried using exact code from other people that worked but it hasn't worked.  It could be a problem on my end

Comment: Here's the first line: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6800 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.9.2) 5 DEC 2018 16:29
entering extended mode

Comment: Am not entirely sure if that is helpful

Comment: I added the used packages to the original question